# My jquery event isn't firing?

Tags: jquery

I'm basically trying to implement:

```
$(function() {
var maxWords = 10;
var wordCounts = {};
$("#a").keyup(function() {
    var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
    wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
    var finalCount = 0;
    $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
        finalCount += v;
    });
    $('#finalcount').val('Words: ' + finalCount);
    if(finalCount > maxWords){
        $("#a").val(a.value.slice(0,-2));
    };
}).keyup();
});
```

HEre's the example Im using: http://jsfiddle.net/YJVPZ/80/

My version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FsbJ3/

For some reason, mine isn't working. I don't really understand jquery or javascript events very well so I'm sure there's something I"m  missing, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. What I"m tyring to do is limit the number of words that can go into a textarea box. Any advice> Thank you very much.

Comment: It appears to work for me in your fiddle. What make you think it isn't working?

Comment: The counter is working, but the rest isn't. AT least not for me. I can type in as many words as I wish, there's no stopping me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FsbJ3/1/

Comment: Can we see the html, it has and error in the jsfiddle

Comment: The part that removes any of the words past 10. IF you look at the example fiddle, it auto-removes anything after 10 words. It's not perfect, but it works. Mine isn't doing that. It's JUST updating the counter.

Comment: `a.value` Where are you setting `a`?

Comment: @JoshAlcorn If you limit the number of words but not the number of characters, people will bypass it avoiding spaces.

Comment: @Oriol I completely agree, but this is the way the client wants it.  Thanks to each of you for helping me discover my dumb mistake. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable "a" is not defined, nor does an element exist with that `id`:

```js
$("#a").val(a.value.slice(0,-2)); // throws error "a is not defined"
```

You can use "this" to refer to the `#a` element you've selected:

```
$("#a").val(this.value.slice(0,-2));  // "this" refers to "#a"
```

[Working Example (jsfidde)](http://jsfiddle.net/FsbJ3/6/)

---

Alternatively, you can use `additional_comments.value` which will refer to the `id` of an element. This is how the example you used references "a", but you've changed the `id` of the element in your code to "additional_comments":

```
$("#additional_comments").val(additional_comments.value.slice(0,-2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FsbJ3/7/

Comment: I noticed that while looking at @aperture's solution. I must have pasted the wrong one into my jfiddle. For some reason now my textarea is broken, but I'm sure I'll figure that out. Thanks.

Comment: That is right. To see this kind of errors you can use a javascript console (Chrome Ctrl + Shift + J). My console gives the feedback after 10 words:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"  Then you click on the line number and you can see where it breaks..